# How to use Microsoft Streets & Trips on Android?

Tags: maps

Is there any way to use Microsoft Streets & Trips on an android device such as Galaxy Tab 2 or Google Nexus?

Comment: Did they make an Android app? Is there a web app that'll work on a mobile device? If not, then no.

Comment: No they don't have an app. I'm looking for an emulator or a terminal app which hosts by a platform like Citrix or Windows Azure. I'll probably setup my own terminal server and try to access it on android

Comment: Your question really is: "How do I run an arbitrary Windows program on Android?"

Comment: @AlEverett Well, i opened a related topic here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/how-to-open-a-remoteapp-by-a-rdp-file-on-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several RDP/VNC application on Android, which can be used to "run" any Windows application.

What you basically need to do is fairly straightforward:

1. Setup a server or virtual machine running a Windows machine
2. Install a [RDP](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=rdp&c=apps)/[VNC](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=vnc%20&c=apps) viewer on your Android
3. Configure the viewer to connect to the server

Citrix and Azure virtualization platform can be accessed by regular off-the-shelf RDP viewer. As an alternative, many open source or off-the-shelf virtualization software like VirtualBox or VMWare also supports RDP or VNC protocol for remote displays of their virtual machines.

How to set up the server is outside the scope of [android.se], try [superuser] or [serverfault]. Once the server is setup, it's fairly straightforward to setup the Android part, come back with a more specific question if you had trouble when you get there.